# How to order results by using order items in IN(...)?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need to order results in the same order, as they are in `IN(...)` clausule. How to do this? For example:

```
SELECT id, name, desc FROM my_table WHERE id IN (8, 4, 19, 48, 15)
```

So I need to have results ordered in this order `8, 4, 19, 48, 15`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `order by field`

```
WHERE id IN (8, 4, 19, 48, 15)
order by field(id,8, 4, 19, 48, 15);
```

Answer (score -1):

## mySQL:

You need to append `ORDER BY FIELD(id,7,5,3,1)`

`SELECT id, name, desc FROM my_table WHERE id IN (7,5,3,1) ORDER BY FIELD(id,7,5,3,1);`